# having problems looping through elements using while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to loop through a collection of divs and randomly fade them out when a click event is triggered but at the moment I have to continually click to fade the other divs all out. I would rather click a div and have all its divs randomly fade out. I have added some console.logs into the while loop and everything seems to work fine, problem is when I try to fadeout the actual elements. If anyone could help that would be great?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/sdpzJ/7/

Comment: Please post some relevant code here and please don't sign your posts

Comment: Hi, link to fiddle in post and signature removed :)

Comment: Great. Now if you can post the relevant code here on SO we may be able to help you with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to throw this out there, too. Simplified.

```
$(function() {
    var $ctn = $('#container .ctn');

    function randomFadeOut() {
        var $r = $ctn.not($(this));
        var e = 0;
        while (e < $ctn.length) {
            $r.eq(e).delay(Math.random() * 500).animate({ opacity: 0 });
            e++;
        }
    }

    $ctn.hide().click(randomFadeOut).each(function(v) {
        $(this).delay(50 * v).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/sdpzJ/15/

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but here's a possible solution:

```
function randomFadeOut(i){  
    var random;
    var e = 0;
    while (e < ctnLength) { 
        random = Math.random() * 1000;
        $(ctn[e]).not(i).delay(random).animate({ opacity : 0 });
        e++;
    }        
}
```

This will fade out all the divs at random times when you click on one.

[I updated your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/sdpzJ/12/).

Answer (score 2):

Your random number generator is **outside** of your loop - so you only get one random number over and over.

Try this:

```
 function randomFadeOut(i){  
        var random      
        for (var e=0;e<ctnLength;e++) {
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctnLength);
            $(ctn[random]).not(i).animate({ opacity : 0 });
        }        
    }
```

Of course, since this is random, the same cells can be selected more than once, which will leave a number of cells behind.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better and more efficient randomFade function:

```
function randomFadeOut(i){          
    var tmp = ctn.toArray();
    tmp.sort( function(){ return Math.floor( Math.random()*3 ) -1; } );
    for( var i=0; i<tmp.length; ++i ){
        $(tmp[i]).delay(100 * i).fadeOut();
    }
}
```

This way, you only go once through the array
I updated your fiddle with it as well to see it in action :)